# Change Column Name in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql

After searching I can't figure out what I need to do in ALTER TABLE `genres` to change the col `id` to `genre_id` any ideas?

Comment: rahul has the answer, for reference see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html

Comment: I looked through that but kept getting Syntax errors.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
alter table genres change id genre_id int(10) auto_increment;
```

Comment: @Johnny ALTER TABLE record CHANGE id genre_id INT(10) AUTO_INCREMENT ; add auto_increment

Comment: Ok it didn't keep the definitions.