# Rename a column in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, rename, alter

I am trying to rename a column in `MySQL` community server `5.5.27` using this SQL expression:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_col_name TO new_col_name;
```

I also tried

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME old_col_name TO new_col_name;
```

But it says:

> Error: check the Manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename a table column in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002340/how-to-rename-a-table-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 753, accepted):

Use this query:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE oldcolname newcolname datatype(length);
```

The `RENAME` function is used in `Oracle` databases.

```
ALTER TABLE tableName RENAME COLUMN oldcolname TO newcolname datatype(length);
```

---

[@lad2025](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49925232/4762528) mentions it below, but I thought it'd be nice to add what he said. Thank you @lad2025!

You can use the `RENAME COLUMN` in MySQL 8.0 to rename any column you need renamed.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_col_name TO new_col_name;
```

[ALTER TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html):

> **RENAME COLUMN:**
>
> - Can change a column name but not its definition.
> - More convenient than CHANGE to rename a column without changing its definition.

Comment: Can you have columns with the same name - or why does the datatype it was have to be specified?

Comment: @Lealo As the command says, `CHANGE` changes the column on a table and its type. The MYSQL docs state: `Attributes present in the original definition but not specified for the new definition are not carried forward.`. Meaning you have to specify the table definitions or they will not be used for that column. If you only want to change a column's datatype, simply leave out the `newcolname`

Comment: @Flimm you're right again. Oracle docs; `In MySQL, the quote character is the backtick. If the SQL mode ANSI_QUOTES is set, double quotes can also be used to quote the identifiers. In Oracle, identifiers are quoted using double quotation marks.` Aaaand edited. I need coffee..

Comment: @JorgeMachado It works just fine. I believe it is not my example that is creating errors for you. Check the syntax, make sure you are using the right example (Top for MySQL, bottom for OracleDB).

Comment: I tried it on my mysql-8.0.11-winx64 and it did not work. Worked when I left the quotes out completly: .....->
ALTER TABLE tableName CHANGE oldcolname newcolname datatype(length);

Comment: Thank you @Smogen! That's odd. Backticks are supposed to be the default quote character for MySQL. Are you sure you didn't use `"` instead of `\``?

Comment: @RizkyFakkel absolutely sure. Maybe its OS dependent?

Comment: I agree, but I'm assuming renaming a column doesn't happen often in bigger applications, and if they do they are probably tested on a test environment beforehand. Maybe MariaDB will come with an equivalent of `RENAME COLUMN x TO y` in the future.

Comment: In MySQL (`MYSQL STATUS` shows `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.27, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper`), I get `Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL Syntax;...near 'COLUMN thread_id TO threadId'...` for the query  `ALTER TABLE comment RENAME COLUMN thread_id TO threadId;`. I also tried adding backticks `\``. I ended up using `CHANGE`.

Comment: Does this operation delete constraints on the column?
EDIT: after checking `information_schema.key_column_usage`, it seems the column name in constraints is updated with this operation.

Comment: Back ticks are not needed usually in MySQL unless the table or column name or function name, etc. is a reserved word or illegal names [like with special characters or embedded spaces. The back tick is also like [] square brackets in SQL Server are used in like manner to allow for names that are not normally legal or a reserved word.

Comment: Your answer seems *slightly* misleading. It wasn't working for me until I reads further down to another answer where someone else had done the same but without the quotation marks. Removing them worked for me.

Comment: Just a quick heads-up - you need to include the entire "column definition", not just `datatype(length)` ([docs for ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)).

Comment: Which form is standard SQL?

Comment: I hate that you have to provide the full column definition to "rename" a column. Wish I could create an alias or something that does this for me because I always forget.

Answer (score 92):

In Server version: 5.6.34 MySQL Community Server

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
CHANGE COLUMN old_column_name new_column_name data_type;
```

Comment: absolutely dont use DROP and ADD. you will lose all data by doing this

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Comment: Just a quick heads-up - you need to include the entire "column definition", not just `datatype` ([docs for ALTER TABLE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)).

Comment: This helped me as the additional 'TO' in other solutions is what was stopping me. Once I removed it, all was well.

Answer (score 49):

From **MySQL 5.7 Reference [Manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html)**.

Syntax :

> ALTER TABLE t1 CHANGE a b DATATYPE;

e.g. : for **Customer** TABLE having COLUMN ***customer_name***, ***customer_street***, ***customercity***.

And we want to change **customercity** TO **customer_city** :

```
alter table customer change customercity customer_city VARCHAR(225);
```

Answer (score 36):

From MySQL 8.0 you could use

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN old_col_name TO new_col_name;
```

> [ALTER TABLE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html):
>
> **RENAME COLUMN:**
>
> - Can change a column name but not its definition.
> - More convenient than CHANGE to rename a column without changing its definition.

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc21e8c179aa5325d9f337c54cb0e63f)**

Answer (score 11):

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name` CHANGE `$old_column_name` `new_column_name` VARCHAR(40)
```

this is working for me

Comment: Please, add an explanation. See [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 7):

You can use following code:

```
ALTER TABLE `dbName`.`tableName` CHANGE COLUMN `old_columnName` `new_columnName` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL ;
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Changing name in MySQL we have to use "ALTER" table command followed by "CHANGE". Below is the query.

`ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE COLUMN oldcolname newcolname datatype;`

`ALTER TABLE tablename CHANGE oldcolname newcolname datatype;`

PS- You can add "COLUMN" word or ignore in the query. It will work same.

"RENAME" is used in Oracle database.

Answer (score 3):

### Remember the backticks

Something that threw me off and that I'm mentioning here explicitly since no other answer seems to - column names need to be surrounded by backticks, of all things. SQL is the only language I've ever come across that insists on backticks for quoting, and the pseudocode of the other answers don't even make it clear that quoting is needed at all.

**For MySQL 8 onwards:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN `old_col_name` TO `new_col_name`;
```

**For MySQL 7 and earlier:**

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE `old_col_name` `new_col_name` datatype(length);
```

Comment: I like this answer because I can quickly see which commands work for which MySQL versions

Answer (score 2):

**Rename column name in mysql**

```
alter table categories change  type  category_type varchar(255);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

In mysql your query should be like

```
ALTER TABLE table_name change column_1 column_2 Data_Type;
```

you have written the query in Oracle.

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

Syntax: ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_column_name new_column_name datatype;

If table name is **Student** and column name is **Name**.
Then, if you want to change **Name** to **First_Name**

```
ALTER TABLE Student CHANGE Name First_Name varchar(20);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE old_column_name new_column_name columnDataType;
```

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of many of the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html

For MySQL 8

```
alter table creditReportXml_temp change column applicationID applicantID int(11);
```

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

for mysql version 5

`alter table *table_name* change column *old_column_name* *new_column_name* datatype();`

Comment: This answer doesn't add much value to the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

For **MySQL** <= 8

```
ALTER TABLE table_names CHANGE `old_column_name` `new_column_name` varchar(50);
```

Comment: How does this answer differ from mine?

Comment: I did not get an answer.but I with (`) got the answer

Comment: it's not working for me and is through an error.

Comment: This appears to be just a repeat of many of the existing answers.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful of most of the answers above. I lost my default value following the accepted answer.

If your column has a default value or other non-default values the correct syntax for MySql 5 is:

`ALTER TABLE table_name CHANGE col1 col2 column_definition;`

From the Manual:
For column definition changes using CHANGE or MODIFY, the definition must include the data type and all attributes that should apply to the new column, other than index attributes such as PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE. Attributes present in the original definition but not specified for the new definition are not carried forward. Suppose that a column col1 is defined as INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'my column' and you modify the column as follows, intending to change only INT to BIGINT:

ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 BIGINT;
That statement changes the data type from INT to BIGINT, but it also drops the UNSIGNED, DEFAULT, and COMMENT attributes. To retain them, the statement must include them explicitly:

ALTER TABLE t1 MODIFY col1 BIGINT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 1 COMMENT 'my column';

Comment: @rinogo I thought that your comment on a couple of posts should be an answer, since I got burned without it.

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked when I had a column with parenthesis.

Then I tried ` and the magic worked. So if you have a special character in your column by mistake and you want to rename it, use **`** for the name of the existing column. For example:

ALTER TABLE table_name RENAME COLUMN `column(old)` TO `new_column`;

Answer (score -1):

Posting it here, it helps helps else ignore it but when trying to use the Change Column and Rename column functions it is throwing me an error.
So figured I would see what statement is generated when we go ahead and rename the column by going into table properties. Below is the command been generated.

```
EXEC DB.sys.sp_rename N'db.tablename.TrackingIDChargeDescription1' , N'ChargeDescription1', 'COLUMN';
```

I used and renamed bunch of columns in table.