# I cannot change databases column

Tags: mysql, mariadb

## I cannot change databases column

### My Env

MacOS Mojave, MySQL Server version: 10.1.39-MariaDB Source distribution

### why

Making a CRUD app, but I want to change table column, 
from `text` to `desc`, so I searched and used alter 
command, but right SQL command returns error messages.

### My table

```
MariaDB [cake_cms]> describe interns;
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| email    | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name     | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| text     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location | varchar(64)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

```
MariaDB [cake_cms]> Alter Table interns Rename Column text to desc;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version 
for the right syntax to use near 'Column text to desc' at line 1
```

#### Refered

https://www.dbonline.jp/mysql/table/index18.html
says to use

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
CHANGE COLUMN old_name TO new_name;
```

[Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)
This site says:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName RENAME COLUMN "oldcolname" TO "newcolname" datatype(length);
```

So I write

```
alter table interns rename column "name" to "newname" varchar(255);
```

But returned syntax error message....

I do not know what to do. Please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

desc is a sql command so you can't name your table like this

Comment: alter table interns rename column "name" to "newname" varchar(255);
also causes the error

Comment: try: ALTER TABLE table CHANGE COLUMN name newName varchar(5)

Comment: ```MariaDB [cake_cms]> alter table interns change column name newName varchar(5);
Query OK, 6 rows affected, 2 warnings (0.02 sec)
Records: 6  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 2``` It worked!! Thankyou !!!

Comment: Backtics (`) are what you put around column names, not quotes (") or (').