# How to rename a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to rename a column in a table in my DB. I already tried

```
ALTER TABLE TableName RENAME COLUMN OldColumnName TO NewColumnName
```

and i am getting an error reply saying - `You have an error in your SQL syntax`; Please whats the right syntax for this? Thanks.

Comment: See the manual for the syntax for modifying column details in MySQL

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)

Comment: Alternatively, it might help if you provided the actual error. Note that you cannot rename a column to be a reserved word.

Comment: @NigelRen Yea. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using this syntax:

```sql
ALTER TABLE TableName CHANGE OldColumnName NewColumnName varchar(10) ;
```