# STRING, STRING(255) or VARCHAR (255)?

Tags: mysql, sql, knex.js

I use `knex` and have a MySql db table that was created with the following:

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
    return knex.schema.table("members", (table) => {
        table.string("member_activation_hash", 255);
        table.dateTime("member_activation_sent_at");
    });
};
```

Now I would like to change (only) the name of both columns, and was thinking of the following:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.raw(
        "ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `member_activation_hash` `user_activation_hash` STRING DEFAULT NULL",
        "ALTER TABLE `members` CHANGE `member_activation_sent_at` `user_activation_sent_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL"
    );
};
```

But I'm not sure about `STRING` on line 3. When it was created it included `255` but I don't think `STRING(255)` is an option and `VARCHAR(255)` would change the data type (which I don't want). What would be the correct way to only change the name of `member_activation_hash`?

**Update**: So I now have:

```
exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.raw(
        "ALTER TABLE `members` RENAME COLUMN `member_activation_hash` TO `user_activation_hash`",
        "ALTER TABLE `members` RENAME COLUMN `member_activation_sent_at` TO `user_activation_sent_at`"
    );
};
```

But this produces the error:

> migration failed with error: Expected 1 bindings, saw 0 Error:
> Expected 1 bindings, saw 0
> at replaceRawArrBindings (C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\raw.js:141:11)
> at Raw.toSQL (C:\Users\xxx\node_modules\knex\lib\raw.js:78:13)

Comment: There's no column type in MySQL called `string`. That type belongs to Knex and gets translated to the appropriate type supported by the DBMS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just rename the column:

```
ALTER TABLE `members` RENAME COLUMN `member_activation_hash` TO `user_activation_hash`
```

[See the documentation here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks, I've tried it (please see the update to my post) but this produces an error.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with `knex`, which I am not familiar with. However, `ALTER TABLE...RENAME COLUMN...` is how you rename a column in MySQL. Getting it to work with a third-party query builder is something you'll have to work through. But [looking online](https://devhints.io/knex) I see that you might want to look at `knex.schema.table.renameColumn`. Best of luck.

Comment: Thanks, got it to work with: `exports.up = function(knex) {
    return knex.schema.table('members', table => {
        table.renameColumn('member_activation_hash', 'user_activation_hash');
        table.renameColumn('member_activation_sent_at', 'user_activation_sent_at');
 });
};`