# How do I change the name of a column in a sql table

Tags: mysql

This is the table and I'm trying to change 'letter' to 'letters'. I tried

```sql
UPDATE table
SET Field = 'letters'
WHERE Type = 'varchar(32)'
```

but it didn't work

```
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra             |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
| id             | int          | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment    |
| ts             | timestamp    | YES  |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | DEFAULT_GENERATED |
| phrase         | varchar(128) | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| letter         | varchar(32)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| ip             | varchar(16)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| browser_string | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
| results        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL              |                   |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: ```ALTER TABLE `table` RENAME COLUMN `letter` TO `letters`;```

Answer (score 0):

Update is for change data in a table. To change structure of a table you should use `ALTER` command. Visit this link:

[Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)