# Dont change value of column - MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying change the name of a column of my table, but it dont change the name, i have tried this command:

`ALTER TABLE book_loan RENAME COLUMN idbook-loan TO idbook_loan;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)

Comment: it dont works @DaMaGeX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need backticks around the column name with hyphens in it?

Also, you must repeat the data type of the column. Let's say it is `INT` ( you didn't mention it so that's a guess.

You want this.

```
ALTER TABLE book_loan RENAME COLUMN `idbook-loan` TO idbook_loan INT;
```

It's possible MySql doesn't recognize that hyphen-containing name as a schema object name without the backtick delimiters.