# Threw unexpected error in Renaming a column name in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ALTER TABLE
    customer
RENAME COLUMN
    dob TO birthdate date;
```

it threw an error.

The error body says:

> Error Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "TO" at
> position 50) SQL query: Copy
>
> ALTER TABLE customer RENAME COLUMN dob TO birthdate date
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'COLUMN
> dob TO birthdate date' at line 3

Comment: This question has already been answered here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql

Comment: Can you check this? https://snipboard.io/5HjhPa.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ALTER TABLE customer CHANGE dob birthdate date;
```

RENAME COLUMN TO is only used to change name, and in Oracle databases.