# Renaming a column in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
ALTER TABLE departments
RENAME COLUMN department_name TO dept_name VARCHAR(50);
```

Why I am getting this error[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7JLF3.jpg)

Comment: `RENAME COLUMN` must be used for to rename the column **only**. You cannot specify the datatype there, even when it is not changed.

Comment: On the screenshot the source of error is missed space between the name of the table and `RENAME` keyword. This causes the `departmentsRENAME` to be distinguished as the table name, and `COLUMN` keyword is distinguished as incorrect ALTER TABLE command. I.e. a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hello, why don't you try this instead:

ALTER TABLE `table` CHANGE `actualName` `newName`

good luck have fun coding

Answer (score 0):

could be you need  CHANGE

```
ALTER TABLE departments CHANGE department_name  dept_name VARCHAR(50);
```

or only RENAME

```
 ALTER TABLE departments
 RENAME COLUMN department_name TO dept_name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your version of MariaDB.

Try this query :

```
ALTER TABLE departments CHANGE COLUMN department_name dept_name VARCHAR(50);
```

Look here :

- [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql?rq=1)
- https://www.techonthenet.com/mariadb/tables/alter_table.php