# How to change column names in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I am having such a hard time changing the column name. I KNOW my syntax is right yet I am getting an error message.

I am using this syntax:

```
    ALTER TABLE Customers RENAME COLUMN CustomerID TO CollaboratorID;
```

I keep getting this error message,
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'COLUMN CustomerID TO CollaboratorID' at line 2

PLEASE HELP.

Comment: It may be a version issue. Using dbfiddle.uk, the it works MySQL 8 but not 5.6 for example https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=7b12290f66805e660eee0fb2de9ac52e

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rename a column in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)

Comment: Consider using Google search for example  mysql 8.0 column rename tutorial  OR  mysql 5.7 column rename tutorial  for more specific advice.

Answer (score 1):

What does `SELECT VERSION()` report? The syntax you show was not supported until MySQL 8.0. Refer to the [ALTER TABLE documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) and make sure to select the version of the product you use.

If you use an older version, you can rename a column this way:

```
ALTER TABLE Customers CHANGE COLUMN CustomerID CollaboratorId ...
```

But with this syntax you must repeat all parts of the column definition, including the data type, `NOT NULL`, `DEFAULT`, etc.

Comment: I am going to school at SNHU and we are using codio and they are using server version 5.5? I will try this! thank you!!