# SOLVED - Unable to update mySQL column name via mysql command line

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I cannot change the column name in a mysql database I created.

I have tried the following commands, and none of them appear to work.

```
alter table (mytablename) CHANGE COLUMN (oldcolumnname) (newcolumnname) varchar(120);
```

```
alter table (mytablename) RENAME COLUMN (oldcolumnname) (newcolumnname) varchar(120);
```

```
ALTER TABLE (mytablename) CHANGE (oldcolumnname) (newcolumnname) varchar(120);
```

Where (mytablename) is the name of the table that I created, (oldcolumnname) is the original column name, and (newcolumnname) is the new column name.

This is a simple to-do list I created to learn MySQL with the following items:

| id | todo | completed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Prepare for Take Off | Yes |
| 2 | Learn some MySQL | Yes |
| 3 | Remember that damn semicolon | No |

In this case, I am trying to alter the column 'todo' to say either 'To Do' or 'To-Do' but every time I try these commands. I keep getting the famous "Check your SQL version manual".

Any hints as to what I might be doing wrong? TIA!

I have reviewed multiple tutorial websites and even reviewed another [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30290880/rename-a-column-in-mysql)

**UPDATE**
The ultimate solution was two-fold. First, I needed to use the **TO** phrase between the column names. Second, the column names do not like special characters.

The query that ultimately worked was:

```
ALTER TABLE mytablename CHANGE COLUMN todo TO ToDo
```

Comment: so they don't appear to work. what *does* happen when you try each?  is there an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the column named todo; you can always change the output when you select like:

```
select id, todo as 'To Do', completed from ...
```

If you feel you really must include a space or - in the column name, in mysql you can use arbitrary identifiers that have not-usually allowed characters by enclosing them in backticks:

```
alter table ... rename column todo to `To Do`
```

but then every time you reference the column in sql you will need to enclose it in backticks:

```
select id,`To Do`,completed from ... where `To Do` like '%learn%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @ysth! The solution ended up being a combination of two things:

I needed to include the TO phrase between the old and new column names. Also, MySQL did not like special characters in column names so my final query was:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable RENAME todo TO ToDo;
```