# changing column name in mysql from sum(xyz) to xyz

Tags: mysql

In MySQL, how do I change the column name of a table from "sum(xyz)", to say "xyz"? I have tried the following solutions for just changing the column name:

[Change Column Name in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224662/change-column-name-in-mysql)

[Rename column SQL Server 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296622/rename-column-sql-server-2008)

However, it always throws up an error saying that the syntax is not right. I feel that it is because of the sum() function, because it doesn't allow me to use SELECT on that column too (when done separately).
Is there any way past this? A solution to access the values in that column without changing the column header is also appreciated!

I am using WAMPSERVER to run MySQL version 5.1.53.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your column name is "sum(xyz)" and you can't do a select because of the "sum()" function.

Try

SELECT ` sum(xyz)` as xyz from mytable;

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable CHANGE COLUMN `sum(xyz)` `xyz` <yourdatatype>;
```

Comment: It says unknown column name 'xyz' in 'field list'. The header of my table is already "sum(xyz)"

Comment: then please post your query

Answer (score 0):

Use **AS** to make virtual field

Your code will be same as `SELECT SUM(yourField) as xyz FROM table`